# How to use the "Find" function in Excel Programming?

Tags: c++, excel, visual-c++, vba

I am trying to read some values from excel file. For that I need to know the last row of every column. For this I am using find function. But, it is giving run time error. I am using c++. Here is the code

```
Excel::_ApplicationPtr app;
::CoInitialize(NULL);
app.CreateInstance("Excel.Application");
Excel::_WorkbookPtr wbk = app->Workbooks->Open("Algo_Sample.xlsx"));
Excel::_WorksheetPtr sheet = wbk->Sheets->Item[1];
Excel::RangePtr range_Ptr = sheet->GetRange("A:A");
range_Ptr->Find("Subject","A1",Excel::xlValues,Excel::xlWhole,Excel::xlByRows,Excel::xlNext,false,false);
```

I checked with the debugger, the error is in last line. This is the snap shot of the excel file
      [image]

I will be very thankful to the person who sheds light on this issue

Note: I am using windows XP, Visual Studio 2008,office 2007,c++.

Comment: Actual error numbers/messages are always helpful.  You're searching for "sibject" but your column has "subjects". Is that intentional?

Comment: Also... .Find returns a range reference (or Nothing/Null if the value isn't found), and you're not setting anything to its return value.

Comment: @Tim Oh yes. But on the above cases also, it shouldn't give runtime error.

Comment: @Tim There are no specific errors. Just "The application asked the runtime to terminate it in an unusual way".

Comment: Have you tried assigning the return value to something? Did that fix the problem?

Comment: @Tim I tried that also,But still the problem persists.

Comment: Sorry - no other suggestions...

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the link with C++, but within Excel, if you want to assign the last used row of a specific column, I use this:

`MyLastRowCount = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row`

Here the variable `MyLastRowCount` is assigned the row number of the last used cell in column A.

What it does is, jump to the last available cell (A65536 for xl03, or A1048576 for xl07/10) in column A and then jump up to the first occupied cell from below.

Regards,

Robert Ilbrink

Answer (score 0):

```
    ::Excel::RangePtr range = m_pObject->Cells->Find
    (
        pValue,
        vtMissing,
        ::Excel::XlFindLookIn::xlValues,
        ::Excel::XlLookAt::xlPart,
        ::Excel::XlSearchOrder::xlByRows,
        ::Excel::XlSearchDirection::xlNext,
        false,
        false,
        vtMissing
    );
```